# how can I reference another column inside postgres insert query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert, insert-query

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE tab (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    code TEXT NOT NULL,
    data TEXT
)
```

In some cases, I'd like to insert a new row ensuring that the code column is generated by the id column. In other cases the `code` is provided by the user.

For example:

```
INSERT INTO tab(code, data) VALUES ('code: ' || id::TEXT, 'my data');
```

The expected result is something like:

| id | code | data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | code: 1 | abc |
| 2 | code: 2 | xyz |

```
INSERT INTO tab(code, data) VALUES ('user.provided.code', 'my data');
```

The expected result is something like:

| id | code | data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | code: 1 | abc |
| 2 | code: 2 | xyz |
| 3 | user.provided.code | xyz |

Is it possibile in one statement?

Comment: Don't do it. You would be exposing the PK value. PK's job only is to be unique. Use a secondary generated key if you want to expose it somewhere (UI, external app, client, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to default the `coder` to something based on the `id`.  Unfortunately, this doesn't work in Postgres:

```
create table tab (
    id   integer primary key generated always as identity,
    code text not null default ('code '||id::text),
    data text
);
```

One option is a single statement that does both an `insert` and `update`:

```
with i as (
      insert into tab (code, data)
           values ('', 'my data'
           returning *
     )
update tab
    set code = 'code: ' || id::TEXT
    where tab.id in (select i.id from i);
```

Another is to use a trigger that assigns the value.

Answer (score 0):

Use `INSERT INTO .. SELECT` as follows:

```
INSERT INTO tab(code, data) 
select 'code: ' || id::TEXT, 'my data' from tab;
```

**Note:** In newly added data(above insert), you are missing to add id column data or I think it is auto generated.